# Trying to replace and make a 3-way dimmer switch work

Tags: electrical, lighting, switch

We are replacing all of the outlets and switches in our house. This one set of lights can be controlled by either a switch or a dimmer that is on another wall. The only problem is the switch has to be turned on for the dimmer to be able to turn the lights on or off. I replaced the switch with a new 3-way switch. I noticed that the old one was also a 3-way. Then I decided to replace the dimmer but there were only 2 wires connected to it. A red and a black. The same black was also connected to another switch in the same box but controls an outside light. I noticed the red wire came out of one cable and the black wire came out of another. I hooked these 2 up to the dimmer, putting the red on the contact with the different colored screw. The light would work with it this way but it still required me to have the switch on the other wall on. I tried to attach the white wire coming out of the same cable as the black but when I flipped the switch, it popped and wouldn't work anymore. I hooked up another dimmer but this time connected the white wire that was in the same cable as the red but then I couldn't get the lights to turn on with the dimmer or the switch. I noticed the black wire that was in the same cable as the red was sitting in there with barely any of the wire stripped. It made me wonder if it may have broke and was some how connected to the old dimmer at one point. I can take pictures and get any other information needed.  The dimmer is a Lutron TGCL-153PH-WH.

[image: first box]

[image: second box]

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring in the switch boxes?

Comment: I just updated the original post with a picture

Comment: As to the other switch box?

Comment: The switch on the left of second picture and dimmer on the right of the first picture control the same set of lights

Comment: Can you get us larger photos?

Comment: Also, what make and model is the three-way dimmer in question?

Comment: How are these? http://s394.photobucket.com/user/arickdm/library/house

Comment: I would be okay with just installing a switch also. I would just like both switches to work independently. The dimmer I bought is a Lutron. Tgcl-153ph-wh

Comment: use [imgur](https://imgur.com) instead of photobucket (photobucket is a nightmare to extract images from)

Comment: Here you go. I could email them to you if needed. http://imgur.com/a/GIG7p

Comment: How open are you to running new wires?

Comment: I would rather not. If that's what it would take then I would rather just leave it the way it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The good news -- you can do this.

Contrary to my previous version of the answer (which mixed up which switch was paired with which dimmer), the 3 wire cable between the RH dimmer in the top image and the LH switch in the bottom picture means that you *can* do this without pulling wire.  Take the black from the 2 wire cable and connect it to the black screw on the dimmer.  Then connect the red and capped off black from the 3 wire cable to the brass screws on the dimmer, and your 3 way switch *should* work properly.  If it doesn't, post another question linked to this one with a photo of the light box.

Comment: What about the white wires that aren't connected to anything. I have one in the same cable as the black and one in the same cable as the red. Also, what's with the black wire that isn't used? It's in the same cable as the red.

Comment: The white wires are important as they are how power gets back to the utility from your loads (lights, appliances, etal)

Comment: So I can't connect one of those to the dimmer to get it to work right? Right now all the white are just connected to each other

Comment: All the grounds are also all connected to each other

Comment: @Devin -- no, the dimmer will say on the instructions if it needs a neutral.

Comment: @Devin -- see my revised answer (I paired the wrong two things)

Comment: I did what you said. Now this switch works as long as the other is flipped down and the other switch works as long as this one is flipped down. The other switch has the red on the colored screw with a white and a black connected to the brass screws.

Comment: @Devin -- we'll need to see the inside of the box for the light these switches control to tell more.  I suspect one of the travellers is open somewhere...

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/3gUro

Comment: @Devin -- what's with the NM cable entering stage left in your photos?

Comment: There are 3 lights that these switches control. I believe it is just running to another light. This was all here when I get the house so I don't know if anything was done right or not

Comment: In those photos, which cables run back to the switches and which go onward to the other lights?

Comment: I'm not sure. I just left and won't be back until tomorrow but I believe the red, white and ground are the ones going to the switch. It looks like that may have been the original light before these 3 were put in

Comment: Right -- where's the black wire from that cable, though?

Comment: I didn't notice it. I'll have to take a closer look

Comment: There's a black wire in there but capped. Swap the red and and black at the lights then?

Comment: Hrm...where does the cable from the other switch go?!

Comment: http://imgur.com/TM7tVbq